# Is there any way to easily add ChromeDriver to a program

Tags: selenium, github, selenium-chromedriver

I find myself using Selenium for web automation a lot, so I end up using ChromeDriver a lot as well. How I currently add it to all my projects is I make a copy of chromedriver.exe and add the copy to all of my projects. Then I tell my program where chromedriver.exe is with the following code:

```
String userPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", userPath + "/chromedriver.exe");
```

Making a new .exe for each project is annoying and I'm wondering if there is a better way

I know a lot of people suggest putting one chromedriver.exe on your computer and just setting the path to the driver and doing something like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Path\\chromedriver.exe");
```

My problem with this is that if I want to move the program to a different computer or onto a server I need to change this path to a new instance of a chromedriver.exe.

I'm wondering if its possible to upload chromedriver to github and then set the path to your repository where you stored chromedriver.exe, so you might have something like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "https://github.com/Tryanno5/chromeDriver/blob/main/chromedriver.exe");
```

(This doesn't work, I already tried, this is just an example)

Is there some way to get chromedriver.exe online where it can always be accessed?
Or is there a better way to get it into all projects without always having to reference a specific copy on my computer?

Comment: If it was python, would have been more easier since there is an auto installer API, see here - https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the `WebDriverManager` check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

Add the dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Setup driver

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: This is perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I can easily add ChromeDriver to my projects. I will say that I still need to add the maven dependency to each project, but thats much easier then copy and pasting a copy of ChromeDriver into each project. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If it was python, would have been more easier since there is an auto installer API, see here -

**Installation**

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

```
Just type import chromedriver_autoinstaller in the module you want to use chromedriver.
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

See here for [more](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm using Java so I can't use this solution